# How to retrieve GtkWindow Inside GtkEventBox?

Tags: gtk

I want to retrieve GtkWindow inside GtkEventBox.
So I used event_box->window, it is not giving any error but i am getting error GTK_IS_WINDOW fails.

or do i have to do it in the expose event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GtkEventBox](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkEventBox.html) does not contain a [GtkWindow](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkWindow.html). It contains a [GdkWindow](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdk/stable/gdk-Windows.html), which is what the window member will contain.

Comment: So can I set transparency to GdkWindow?